qiskit IBM runtime issue api code 3211
I am trying to qiskit nature circuit on qiskit and since I am getting errors on local machine, I am using qiskit backend for the same. However I am getting below error -
qiskit version 0.46
qiskit-nature version 0.7.2
IBMJobFailureError: 'Job failed: Error code 3211; Job not valid. SymEngine-0.11 was asked to deserialize an object created using SymEngine-0.13.'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Deserialization fails if Qiskit and IBM runtime are not using the same symengine version. Pinning your local symengine version by running python -m pip install symengine~=0.11.0 will fix this issue.
